# Download a file from NestJS (without saving it )

Tags: node.js, nestjs, pdfkit, node-streams

I want to make client download a pdf file generated from my back-end. I am using the [pdfkit-lib](https://pdfkit.org/) to generate my pdf file. From the NestJs [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files), I decided to use `StreamableFile` from a `DuplexStream` (pdfkit-lib works with a `WritableStream` and `StreamableFile` with a `ReadableStream`) :

```
@Get('/generate-file')
generateFile(): StreamableFile {
  const fileStream = new stream.Duplex();
  const doc = new pdfkit()
  doc.pipe(fileStream);
  // do stuff
  doc.end();
  return new StreamableFile(fileStream);
}
```

But I end up with this error :

```
Error: The _write() method is not implemented
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Duplex.Writable._write (node:internal/streams/writable:588:11)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Duplex.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at PDFDocument.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at PDFDocument.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at PDFDocument.Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:527:10)
    at flow (node:internal/streams/readable:1012:34)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:993:3)
```

It can make it works with `fs.createWriteStream` and `fs.createReadStream` but I don't want to create the file on my server (and there is no callback on StreamableFile to delete). Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to do this without the overhead of writing to a temporary file. You can try streaming directly into the `res` stream, something like:

```
@Get('/generate-file')
generateFile(@Res() res: Response): void {
   const filename = 'SomeFileName.pdf';
   const doc = new PDFDocument({ bufferPages: true });
   const stream = res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-disposition': `attachment;filename=${filename}.pdf`,
   });
   doc.on('data', (chunk) => stream.write(chunk));
   doc.on('end', () => stream.end());

   doc
     .font('Times-Roman')
     .fontSize(12)
     .text(`just a test`);
   doc.end();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I end up using `fs.createWriteStream` and `fs.createReadStream` by deleting the created file :

```
@Get('/generate-file')
generateFile(@Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response): StreamableFile {
  const fileName = '';
  const filePath = '';
  
  const doc = new pdfkit()
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
  // do stuff
  doc.end();

  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  fileStream.on('end', () => {
    try {
      fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException('An error occurred while removing the file.');
    }
  });

  res.set({
    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`,
  });
  return new StreamableFile(fileStream);
}
```